# different structure of datasource for kendo grid leads to issues in filtering

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a local datasource in the structure of the below:

```
Account:null
AccountId:null
Address:Object
 ---> Country:Object
            --->Name:"Afghanistan"
CreatedBy:"System"
CreatedDateTime:"/Date(1457934873890)/"
Id:"ad92aa1e-5b48-41bf-a68a-52dfcab009e3"
IsDeleted:false
IsReferred:false
IsSystemData:true
```

Here I'm using some of the fields for kendo grid. Problem occurs when perform filter operation for country field. While binding the datasource to column

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Address.Country.Name).ClientTemplate(" #= Address.Country ? Address.Country.Name : '' # ").Width(110);
```

Country is a optional field in the form. If the user leaves that as empty, datasource will not be country name property. It will leave Address.Country as null. While filtering, for those empty country fields the error occurs as `"Cannot read property of Name of null value"`.

Please guide me to overcome the situation. I tried by altering the datasource that is iterating the datasource and add a name property as empty to country object if it is null to achieve same structure for all the rows in datasource. Is there a way to avoid the iteration as our db has bulk datas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Someone correct me if im wrong.
The thing is that when you filter, the code tries to filter the binding not the template. thats why you have nullable values, you can edit the datasource before and do the condition before and then bind without having to do a client template.

you can also put some other "sort":

`columns.Bound(c => c.Id).ClientTemplate(" #= Address.Country != null ? Address.Country.Name : '' # ")`

This wont work? i cannot test because i dont have telerik right now installed.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I think I should bind c.Address.Country.Name only so that I can get the bounded country name in controller to save in db if it has values.

Comment: another solution, create a specific Model to the grid and then when saving you parse to the right object.